# Getting site running in IIS 7 Issues

Tags: iis-7

This is driving me nuts.  I am trying to setup a webiste on our dev server with a specific url name www.mystpidsite.com as an example.  mystupidsite is not the same name as the dev server.

1) specify a specific url to use for the website I create in IIS

2) run it and use that url to access it

I have:

1) created a new site in IIS 7 in Server 2008

2) attempted to access it via the site name which I set to the desired url and port 8888.  So if we want it to be www.mystupidsite.com I setup the website name to mystupidsite in IIS 7.

3) I even tried to create an application under mystupidsite with the same name in IIS 7.

The server is definitely accessible and pingable on the network from my local PC, we have other stuff installed on this new server.  Do I need to create an application or is just creating the website enough in IIS 7?  I specified the IP as the server's IP in the website I made.

For the host name in the bindings of the site I put www.mystupidsite.com

when I try to access the site via www.mystupidsite.com it can't find it and the site in IIS7 on the dev server is running.  It's running on a HyperV instance which is our dev server.  Everything else has worked just fine.  I just wnat to understand how to get a specific url by name setup.

Do I need to add something in the hosts file on the server or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have an entry in dns to be able to hit the server when using www.mystupidsite.com

Because you have the site running on an alternate port you should be able to get to it by http://your-server-IP-address:8888

If you want to test it locally using the host name and do not have access to dns you can add the appropriate entries to the hosts file on your local machine (c:\windows\system 32\drivers\etc\hosts)

Comment: I have always had domain admin rights and I assume if I'm only Local Admin to the dev box in Server 2008, that this is not enough to be able to administrate websites or anything worth while such as the file system on that server.

Comment: You should be able to manage everything local to the server if you actually have local admin rights to it. They may have made you a power user, or removed/granted specific rights through group policy.

Comment: Were you able to access the site by adding the entries to the hosts file on your local machine? It's an OK solution for testing, but ideally you should be able to get a domain admin to add the entries to your local dns so you won't have to go through all this.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to have a site on your dev box answer to both the mystpidsite.com and mystupidsite.com domain names.

Unless you have the domains registered and have your domain's nameserver directing that name to your dev machine, IIS is only going to answer to requests either the machine name on the network or the IP address of your machine (in addition to 127.0.0.1 and localhost).

The only thing you're going to be able to do outside that scenario is set up two sites on two different ports on your machine and access them from http://localhost:80 and http://localhost:8888 (or network computer name equivalent).

Comment: localhost won't work if he has the default empty host header set on one. ;)

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you type 'nslookup www.mystupidsite.com'? Do you get the IP address of the virtual server?

Do you have the windows firewall enabled on the server? if so, did you add an exception for port 8888?

Comment: When I do an nslookup it shows me an address but dns request timed out

Comment: but it gives me a weird servername and another IP, not this server

Comment: I assume we have to have a DNS entry for any urls other than this server name

Comment: yup, looks like DNS is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

add a default binding (no host header / blank) and try accessing it by IP